# air 3.3, new iPad, detection?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I understand air 3.3 scales up images for the new ipad, but is there a way so that I can detect that it is the new ipad and use @2x graphics instead?

I use this to get the width/height but on the new iPad it just returns 1024 x 768 and not 2048 x 1586:

```
var width = Math.max(GlobalVars.vars.stage.fullScreenWidth, GlobalVars.vars.stage.fullScreenHeight);
var height = Math.min(GlobalVars.vars.stage.fullScreenWidth, GlobalVars.vars.stage.fullScreenHeight);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. http://www.overdigital.com/2012/05/08/the-new-retina-ipad-and-adobe-air/